# Android (support library v21) - toolbar как получить высоту

Tags: java, android, android-library

Как получить высоту toolbara. (toolbar создаётся нормально).
При запросе стандартного `getHeight()` выдаёт 0.
Использовать `getMinimumHeight()` не получится,
используется API 11 с подключенной support library v21.

layout.activity_view_large_screen.xml.

```
<LinearLayout
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context="com.android.nik.timeline.ViewLargeScreenActivity"
   tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
   android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/ScreenToolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

<LinearLayout
    android:id = "@+id/windows_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_large_screen);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.ScreenToolbar);
    toolbar.getHeight();//получаем ноль
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну это типично для любого view, размеры в `onCreate`, `onStart` и  `onResume` еще не определены. Вы вызываете этот метод слишком рано.

Первое появление размеров можно отловить вот тут:

```
@Override
 public void onWindowFocusChanged(boolean hasFocus) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
  //Here you can get the size!
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

В `onCreate()` он ещё не прошел стадию `onMeasure()`, поэтому его высота неизвестна. Так будет с любым View. Установите `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` на `ViewTreeObserver`, в нем сразу же его снимите и там высота будет доступна.

```
toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
        toolbar.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);    
        toolbar.getHeight(); // Здесь он известен            
    }
});
```

Comment: спасибо,а в onCreateView высота уже будет известна?

Comment: @NikitaBogdanov, нет, в `onCreateView` её тоже ещё не будет.